# sapply over vector for each element in a list

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

I have a large list that includes extracted terms from a corpus.

```
    mylist <- list(c("flower"), 
               c("plant", "animal", "cats", "doggy"),
               c("tree", "trees", "cat", "dog"))
```

The extracted terms are from a dataframe (as main words, similar words and categories)

```
   ref <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), 
                  main = c("tree", "plant", "flower", "dog", "cat"), 
                  similar = c("trees","plantlike", "flowery", "doggy", "cats"),
                  category = c("plant", "plant", "plant", "animal", "animal"))
```

I need to change the list so that I have categories instead of the words. and maybe remove duplicates like this ...

```
    needed <- list("plant",
                   c("plant", "animal", "animal", "animal"),
                   c("plant", "plant", "animal", "animal"))
    
    orbetter <- list("plant",
                   c("plant", "animal"),
                   c("plant", "animal"))
```

but I don't know how to sapply for each element of the list. I appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you get from `myList` to `needed`? Are you performing a lookup against `ref`?

Comment: @emilliman5
 yes .. I want to match the words with the reference dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
mylist <- list(c("flower"), 
               c("plant", "animal", "cats", "doggy"),
               c("tree", "trees", "cat", "dog"))

ref <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), 
                  main = c("tree", "plant", "flower", "dog", "cat"), 
                  similar = c("trees","plantlike", "flowery", "doggy", "cats"),
                  category = c("plant", "plant", "plant", "animal", "animal"))

library(tidyr)

ref_long <- ref %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, category))

lapply(mylist, function(x) unique(ref_long$category[match(x, table = ref_long$value)]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "plant"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "plant"  NA       "animal"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "plant"  "animal"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>